# What's the correct way of port declaration while instantiating modules in Verilog HDL?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

From what I know, if we need to instantiate `module1` in `module2`, then I need to declare all the `inputs` & `outputs` of `module1` as `reg` & `wire` respectively in `module2`.

But often times, I have seen that even with all input-output ports being declared as `reg`, the simulation works. Can someone explain what's the correct way of port declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to declare all signals in module `module2` as `reg`.  However, this is only supported by **SystemVerilog** (IEEE Std 1800).  It is not supported by **Verilog** (IEEE Std 1364).  For example, this syntax is legal in **SystemVerilog**:

```
module module1 (input clk, output data);
endmodule

module module2;
    reg clk, data;
    module1 i0 (.clk(clk), .data(data));
endmodule
```

However, the above is illegal in **Verilog**.  You  need to declare the `module1` output as `wire` for **Verilog**:

```
module module2;
    reg clk;
    wire data;
    module1 i0 (.clk(clk), .data(data));
endmodule
```

Using `wire` is also legal for **SystemVerilog**.

Comment: Do things change if we define `output reg` - ie. does Verilog allow a `reg output port` to be declared as `reg`? Also what's the difference between declaring a port as `wire` or `reg` specifically during instantiation?

Comment: @Killjoy, for a Verilog answer, see my [old answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/245920/6334). For SystemVerilog you may have to ask a new question.